# Add disk to QNap Raid 5

Tags: raid, raid5, qnap

I have a QNap TS-569 Pro configured with Raid 5 of 4 hard drives of 1 Terabyte each.
It has 5 disk slots and I want to increase the size of the Raid of another Terabyte.

Reading the manual seem pretty easy operation, but I have a doubt. After adding the new hard drive to the raid, the QNap will rebuild the raid.
During this time (usually it's pretty long), can I access the data? Or would it be unavailable until the synchronization process finishes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RAID array while it is being reshaped, but access will be slower than normal.

Comment: Ok thanks, and iScsi connections should also work right?

Comment: With the same caveat, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself. Tested on QNap TS-569 Pro configured with Raid 5. If you add a disk to the raid, the data will be unavailable until reshape has finished.
Hence make sure to do this operation on weekends or overnight.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate and unexpected. Any professional grade system should keep the array online during reshaping.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know I was really disappointed when I found out!